# Vue: on div click, go to url defined in data

Tags: vue.js

I have this kind of objects in an array:

```
{
  name: 'name1',
  url: 'http://url-1.tld'
},
{
  name: 'name2',
  url: 'http://url-2.tld'
}
```

On div click, I want to to a window.location.href to the `url`, but I can't seem to get the url from the data to my method.

```
<div v-for="person in persons" v-on:click="select($event)"></div>

select: function(event) {
  window.location.href( ??? )
}
```

Anybody have suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass the `person` as the argument to `select`, not `$event`:

```
<div v-for="person in persons" v-on:click="select(person)"></div>
```

```
select: function(person) {
  window.location.href = person.url;
}
```

Comment: `window.location.href` is not a function.

Comment: @Bert seems to exist https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: @ill In the original answer, `window.location.href` was used as a function (eg. `window.location.href(xxx)`.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works but it refreshes the page. In SPA frameworks we try to avoid refreshing the page so the correct answer is:

Vue: `this.$router.push(person.url)`

Nuxt: `this.$router.push({ name: 'routename' })`